# SQL/PHP INSERT INTO multiple rows with $row

Tags: php, sql

So pretty much my issue is that I need to send multiple SQL entries using information based on another SQL entry.

I've simplified the code down that I was using so it's easily understandable.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT product FROM `cart` WHERE username = '".$user."' LIMIT 10");

while ($rowcart = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {

    $sendorder = "INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, product) VALUES ('NULL', '".$rowcart[0]."')";
    mysql_query($sendorder);  

}
```

When I ran it, it had failed to work; so I tried to `echo $sendorder` to see exactly what was sending and it turns out it's copying the `INSERT INTO` part on each entry, instead of just copying the values.

Example output:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, product) VALUES ('NULL', 'Cakes')
INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, product) VALUES ('NULL', 'Sweets')
INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, product) VALUES ('NULL', 'Cakes')
INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, product) VALUES ('NULL', 'Brownies')
INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, product) VALUES ('NULL', 'Cakes')
```

Comment: enable errors by placing error_reporting(E_ALL), and then run it. Whatever error you see, share it. Also, share the columns details, so that someone can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, what you want to do is to send an unique query, you can do this by appending every value to be inserted at the end of a single query string:

```
<?php
    // code
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT product FROM cart WHERE username='".$user."' LIMIT 10");
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        $rowcart=mysql_fetch_row("$result");
        $sendorder="INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, product) VALUES ('NULL', '".$rowcart[0]."')";
        while($rowcart=mysql_fetch_row($result))
            $sendorder.=", ('NULL', '".$rowcart[0]."')";
        mysql_query($sendorder);
    }
    // code
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You said, "I need to send multiple SQL entries using information based on another SQL entry."  The following approach is more efficient than what you are attempting.  Note that I use neither php nor mysql so I might have some syntax errors.

```
insert into orders
(product)
select product
from cart 
where username = $user
```

As far as the limit 10 goes, if you want to restrict the person to 10 items, you should do something to ensure that only 10 rows go into the cart table.

Answer (score 1):

Mysqli example

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_database');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
     exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT product FROM `cart` WHERE username = ? LIMIT 10");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($product);

 while($stmt->fetch()) {
      $tvalue[] = $product;
 }


 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Orders (product) VALUES (?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("s", $one);

foreach ($tvalue as $one) {
      $stmt->execute();
 }

 printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

 /* close statement and connection */
 $stmt->close();

 /* close connection */
 $mysqli->close();
 ?>
```

Comment: Add some explanation and this would be a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, your `order_id` is a primary key, and `auto_increment`. You can leave that:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (product) VALUES ('Cakes')
```

or if you really want to insert it, then use

```
INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, product) VALUES (NULL, 'Cakes')
```

if you add quotes `'` around it, then it will be parsed as a string. And since, that is not a string, but integer, it will cause syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in a single SQL statement something like this..

```
INSERT INTO Orders(order_id,product) 
SELECT null,product 
FROM cart 
WHERE username = $name    
LIMIT 0,10
```

To refactor even further I would suggest you probably dont need to insert the null value just do:

```
INSERT INTO Orders(product) 
SELECT product 
FROM cart 
WHERE username = $name    
LIMIT 0,10
```

If your table is structured to allow NULL in the order_id col then this will be populated as null by default.

And as Dan just said doesnt seem to be much point putting a limit on either